# Update one form content from another form in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I need to update one form content from another form in jsf.If i give another form id ,it will show an error like component id not found.

My Coding is

```
<h:form id="form1" name="form1">
 <h:commandLink value="Tab1" id="Tab1">
  <f:ajax listener="#{managedBean.tabChange}" event="click" render="form2"></f:ajax>
 </h:commandLink></li>
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2" name="form2">
   <h:outputText value="#{managedBean.text}" id="text"/>
</h:form>
```

in render attribute

@all work for me.
but form2/text won't work .

Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Client IDs are relative to their naming container, so JSF looks for a component with the name `form2` only inside `form1`. If you want to escape from this container, you need to prefix your id with a colon.

So the following should work:

```
<f:ajax listener="#{managedBean.tabChange}" event="click" render=":form2"/>
```